# Laravel Passport implementation on site with user+organizations (like GitHub)

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Laravel Passport supports a different scopes for an user resources. But, if the user has a multiple organizations (like github)? How can we handle same scope but for different organizations?

For example, an application requests token with `place-orders` scope, but the user has many organizations, and he wants to authorize app scopefor only one of them.

Any library or idea for implementation of [Laravael Passport Token Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#token-scopes)?

Comment: Just as an idea: make a policy and do not allow token fetch before you have known organization id.